# Replaces Nulls with 0 without using a function?

Tags: sql, function, null, sybase, isnull

I want to replace null values in a table but without using a function such as isnull because its dealing with a large amount of data and slowing it down.

everywhere online says isnull and coalesce but is there any way without using such functions.
I need this because the query

```
OPENING_OTHER + OPENING_FEE + OPENING_INT AS TOTAL_BALANCE
```

If one value is NULL then the total balance is always null

Cheers

Comment: How about simple `WHERE Field IS NULL` condition ?

Comment: Yeah, why not using something like `UPDATE table SET field=2 WHERE field=NULL`?

Comment: added more to explanation and sybase

Comment: "Slow" == "full table scan".  Which is unavoidable in your scenario - it isn't as though you have an index to identify null columns ;)  It's not that you're using a "function".  "coalesce" or "isnull" are perfectly appropriate choices here.

Comment: They're built in functions and should be vastly quicker than the I/O costs involved in running the rest of your query.

Comment: Is `TOTAL_BALANCE` a column in a table? Or a column in a SELECT query? Or a calculated column (in a table or view?)

Comment: Calculated column in a view

Comment: @RichardC in that case you're going to want to post the view definition.

Comment: Sorry itsin a create table select statement

Comment: `ISNULL` is probably not the cause of your problems.

Comment: @RichardC which makes it not a VIEW. I agree --- the problem here isn't `COALESCE` or `ISNULL` ... the source problem will be identified later.

Comment: Ok thanks for all the feedback, isnull it is

Answer (score 2):

No, how can you do something without doing anything?

You could permanenetly replace the `NULL` values with `0` but that would waste a lot of storage.

Transforming your data in a `SELECT` statement is not terribley costly if you use built in functions designed for that purpose.

---

The use of [coalesce](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc36272_1251/html/commands/X17336.htm) will be the quickest, most effiecient and expediant way to do this.

```
coalesce(OPENING_OTHER, 0) + coalesce(OPENING_FEE, 0) + 
    coalesce(OPENING_INT, 0) AS TOTAL_BALANCE
```

In fact, I'd suggest the actual cost of `coalesce` is so small that its hard to measure.

Comment: +1 I think it's a very good answer :)

Comment: Hi, it is not a presentation concern i edited the question it is making values change to null

Comment: @RichardC I removed that from my answer.